# CodeIgniter Database Error but only one section of app

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have an existing web app but for no apparent reason one section of the app is now displaying the following error:

> A Database Error Occurred
>   Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
>   Filename: core/Loader.php
>   Line Number: 338

The rest of the app works fine and can connect using the same database credentials at `application/config/database.php`

Any help to point me in the right direction in terms of debugging the issue would be welcome.

This is for an existing Linux server, running MySQL 5, PHP 7 and Apache 2.

> A Database Error Occurred
>   Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
>   Filename: core/Loader.php
>   Line Number: 338

Comment: make sure if path is correct in loader file which points to database.php, also if you can share the part of the code of loader.php file

Comment: Show the Controller/method code on which you get this error while accessing it

Comment: check database _name,root,password is correct inside config/database.php?

Comment: your welcome page is working fine or not? Try to retrieve data on welcome page.